# Larger clustered index vs more non clustered indexes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

To give a bit of background, we have a Kimball led Dimensional model star schema with a couple of Measures and Dimensions. We have 2 big Measure tables consisting of about 4 billion rows each, one measure and about 8 keys to dimensions.

So as far as I know, the wider an index the slower it is (number of levels?), same for non-clustered as well as clustered.

I understand that this is very much a "it depends answer" but in general, would it be better to have a narrow clustered index with high usage query led design of narrow non clustered indexes?

And following on that, is it better to have wider non-clustered indexes or rather more non clustered indexes targeting specific use cases?

The reason why I ask this is that we have quite a wide clustered index that includes column a and column b and those same columns are in an index that is quite wide as well. When I then do a query, sql still suggests another new index with column a and column b which seems to me to be quite redundant then?

Any help and advice would be appreciated and feel free to correct any logical gaps/misconceptions I have in my understandings :-).

Comment: Well - *more indexes* always means *more maintenance overhead* - so I try to keep the number of indexes on any table as small as possible. On the other hand, since the clustered index data is the *most replicated* (and most duplicated - after all, the **clustering key** shows up in each and every single non-clustered index, too!) in a SQL Server system, keeping that clustered index lean and mean would be even more important to me.

Comment: Thanks marc. So would you rather say, small clustered index (we do have an identity field on our measures) and then non clustered for query purposes? I seem to find a lot of conflicting info on this.

Comment: Yes, I would **first** make sure to keep the clustered index as small as possible (it should be narrow, unique, static) and then try to add as few nonclustered indices as possible. If you *can*, try to use compound indices based on multiple columns, or try to "extend" indices by adding *included* columns to satisfy queries. Just try to use as few indices as possible, in general

Comment: Great, thanks for the help, more than happy for you to add an answer and I'll accept it.